Laravel Docker: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out
I'm trying to connect mysql database but it's not work. How to fix it?
.env file
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=host.docker.internal
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=sail
DB_PASSWORD=password

config\database file
'connections' => [

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DB_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'laravel'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => env('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4'),
            'collation' => env('DB_COLLATION', 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'),
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
]

docker-compose.yml file
services:
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
        volumes:
            - 'sail-mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
            - './vendor/laravel/sail/database/mysql/create-testing-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10-create-testing-database.sh'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test:
                - CMD
                - mysqladmin
                - ping
                - '-p${DB_PASSWORD}'
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s

And when I run this command docker ps -a, this is the result:
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                         COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS                        PORTS                                                      NAMES
c51aae3e5ba3   sail-8.3/app                  "start-container"        58 seconds ago       Up 56 seconds                 0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5173->5173/tcp                 example-app-laravel.test-1
ac56ca8e33cc   selenium/standalone-chrome    "/opt/bin/entry_poin…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute             4444/tcp, 5900/tcp                                         example-app-selenium-1
35a5a74ba4ae   getmeili/meilisearch:latest   "tini -- /bin/sh -c …"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute (healthy)   0.0.0.0:7700->7700/tcp                                     example-app-meilisearch-1
8cfebdb51c63   mysql/mysql-server:8.0        "/entrypoint.sh mysq…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute (healthy)   0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060-33061/tcp                    example-app-mysql-1
732348f1fba0   axllent/mailpit:latest        "/mailpit"               About a minute ago   Up About a minute (healthy)   0.0.0.0:1025->1025/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8025->8025/tcp, 1110/tcp   example-app-mailpit-1
b3a48ef1a548   redis:alpine                  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute (healthy)   0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp                                     example-app-redis-1
76e1503c8731   sail-8.3/app                  "start-container"        51 minutes ago       Exited (0) 26 minutes ago                                                                api-laravel.test-1
62cce2cb9872   axllent/mailpit:latest        "/mailpit"               52 minutes ago       Exited (0) 26 minutes ago                                                                api-mailpit-1
969da70f2c5d   getmeili/meilisearch:latest   "tini -- /bin/sh -c …"   53 minutes ago       Exited (143) 26 minutes ago                                                              api-meilisearch-1
829e1081c4e1   mysql/mysql-server:8.0        "/entrypoint.sh mysq…"   54 minutes ago       Exited (0) 26 minutes ago                                                                api-mysql-1
ab4872db1051   redis:alpine                  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   54 minutes ago       Exited (0) 26 minutes ago                                                                api-redis-1
a4c4686916a0   selenium/standalone-chrome    "/opt/bin/entry_poin…"   56 minutes ago       Exited (143) 26 minutes ago                                                              api-selenium-1

Yesterday, it was working normally, but today it suddenly cannot connect to the database. I'm just confused. I have tried changing the value of DB_HOST to 127.0.0.1, localhost, and mysql, but it didn't solve the issue.
Thanks for answering.

Are you connecting to sail container? if you did not change docker-compose file, DB_HOST should be mysql. In your question, mysql did not solve the issue, post the docker-compose file and the result of docker ps -a

Yes, I am connecting to the Sail container. I just updated the post. Thank you for trying to help! :)

try to change it back to mysql then run php artisan optimize:clear to clear the cache

btw, can you access your mysql? Based on the container list, mysql is currently running. Check that you can access your container then show database (or if you have phpmyadmin or other db ui)
